# apache not showing images

Tags: css, image, apache, localhost

Just recently I have been unable to view new images through localhost on my mac(OS X 10.9.5).  I'm setting a background image for a webpage through css.  The webpage works and displays the background image for photos I downloaded a week ago, but when I try and update the background photo to a newly downloaded jpg (in the same dir) and view through localhost, the picture will not show up.

I know my code and file path is correct because it works with older photos in the same dir.  When I view the page through my file system `file:///` as opposed to localhost, it works fine and when I upload my files and images to my server everything works fine.  I also have `r/w access` to all folders.  For some reason, I simply cannot view newly downloaded images through localhost.  Not sure if this is relevant but I recently installed 2 software updates:

```
 1) Command line tools (OS X 10.9) version 6.0 and 2) OS X Update Combined version 10.9.5.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Code:

/* Works fine */

```
background-image: url("img/OLD_PIC.jpg");
```

/* 
Does not work when viewing through localhost, but does work when viewing through the filesystem and my server 
*/

```
background-image: url("img/NEW_PIC.jpg");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to change the permission of this file by using this command:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rw /var
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Check the permissions of the new images ( If works -> chmod 777 foldername ).

2) Case 1 dont work - Try:

```
   background-image: url("/img/OLD_PIC.jpg");
```

or

```
   background-image: url("./img/OLD_PIC.jpg");
```

or

```
   background-image: url("../img/OLD_PIC.jpg");
```

One of them should work..

Note: You will probably have to change it back when you deploy to the server..

Comment: I have already tried all 3 ways with multiple different images and still no luck.

Comment: Your new images have the same permissions as the old ones?

Comment: Well that did it!  I was so quick to check my perm's to my dir's I failed to check the perm's for the image.  It looks like the default setting for all newly downloaded images is set to "no access".  Do you know why this is happening?  It was not like this before.

Comment: Use: 
 chmod 777 foldername

Comment: Looks like your problem is resolved, up the response. ;)